# Failed loading the Index Template in Elasticsearch

Tags: elastic-stack, filebeat

I am trying to install ELK for logs centralization. I am following steps described in digital ocean website: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-elasticsearch-logstash-and-kibana-elk-stack-on-ubuntu-14-04

I fail to download the filebeat index template using curl from this link:
 https://gist.githubusercontent.com/thisismitch/3429023e8438cc25b86c/raw/d8c479e2a1adcea8b1fe86570e42abab0f10f364/filebeat-index-template.json

Can someone give me another source to get it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the content of that link:

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "_default_": {
      "_all": {
        "enabled": true,
        "norms": {
          "enabled": false
        }
      },
      "dynamic_templates": [
        {
          "template1": {
            "mapping": {
              "doc_values": true,
              "ignore_above": 1024,
              "index": "not_analyzed",
              "type": "{dynamic_type}"
            },
            "match": "*"
          }
        }
      ],
      "properties": {
        "@timestamp": {
          "type": "date"
        },
        "message": {
          "type": "string",
          "index": "analyzed"
        },
        "offset": {
          "type": "long",
          "doc_values": "true"
        },
        "geoip"  : {
          "type" : "object",
          "dynamic": true,
          "properties" : {
            "location" : { "type" : "geo_point" }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "settings": {
    "index.refresh_interval": "5s"
  },
  "template": "filebeat-*"
}
```

Just make a file called filebeat-index-template.json with this command:

```
touch filebeat-index-template.json
```

Then open the file in an editor like this:

```
nano filebeat-index-template.json
```

Then copy and paste the contents from the link above and save the file (ctrl + x).

After that you should be able to continue through the digital ocean walkthrough at the "load the template" part.

Comment: This helped me a lot. Thank you !